# No Rate Limit On Reset Password in WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, penetration-testing

In my WCF service built on.net framework 4.8, I have a scenario.
During penetration testing, it is discovered that the No Rate limit is not respected. I attempted the settings on the IIS server described in the link below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/dynamicipsecurity/denybyrequestrate
despite the fact that it isn't working

Is there a programmed approach to handle things like limiting a request from the same IP address to 5 requests in a 60-minute period in the case of the reset password method?

Comment: Is there any error message when it doesn't work? Or maybe try the methods under [this heading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/dynamicipsecurity/) as well.

Comment: It is a Penetration Test Case with a "No Rate Limit."
You can hit the same end point numerous times with Postman. If the end point has email sending capabilities, the user's inbox will be flooded.